# Is it correct to say "Keep Your Eyes on the Road" when the person is riding a bike on a ground not on a road?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idioms, idioms-in-context

I heard a lot of people say "**Eyes on the Road**" in action films, but I couldn't see any dictionary mentioning it.

**It seems to mean that you must pay attention when you are driving to avoid accidents.**

Say, a child is riding his bike on a ground or in the playground or on a floor in a house. The child is not riding his bike on a road.

For some reason, he often turn around to look at people, which is dangerous because he might hit his bike on something.

In that particular situation, Is it correct to say "**Keep Your Eyes on the Road**"?

Answer (score 3):

As "**Keep your eyes on the road**" is a set phrase and an idiom, it has come to express the idea of "pay attention to where you are going" more than the literal words of "look at the road".  I have also seen the phrase used in an entirely metaphorical sense, meaning to pay attention to what is happening in your life.  This meaning of "pay attention" is key to the phrase.

As such, **it is an acceptable phrase** to use even when there isn't a literal road to be looked at, such as in your situation with a bicycle on a dirt playground or inside a house.

Comment: It is really important that anyone riding a bicycle on a public road is able to do so without taking their eyes off the road. I recall reading about a very bad accident where the cyclist's father said 'he must have been looking down at the gears'.

Comment: I would probably prefer to say (or shout!)  'Watch (or look) where you are going!" as a more general instruction, not least to avoid mental hesitation by the rider if they are not actually on a road.

Comment: Yes, there are many things you could shout to convey this idea, but "Keep your eyes on the road" is one such thing you can say.  If the danger isn't imminent, a longer phrase should be acceptable.  If the danger is imminent, definitely say something shorter... although in that case, a longer phrase afterwards to reinforce the point would also be acceptable.

Comment: While I agree that 'keep your eyes on the road' can be employed as a general idiom meaning 'remain focused on the task in hand; do not allow yourself to become distracted', I would hesitate to use it to a child on a bicycle unless they are actually on a road (with its dangers and potential obstacles). To say it to a child cycling in a field or playground would be, to me, a bit like saying 'avoid the lions!' when there are only rabbits around. Certainly my son would have stopped the bike, looked at me scornfully, and asked 'What road?'.